# async await blocks the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await

I have written something like;

```
self.handleAction = async function (event) {
    $("#someDivID").show();

    await __method1();
    //log something
    await __method2();

    $("#someDivID").hide();
}
```

The thing is, I know the `__method1()` and `__method2()` will take time to execute and hence I'm using the `async-await` approach here.

The JQuery `show` and `hide` methods are supposed to show a certain div while the processing is happening (kind of like a loading gif.) I'm using the same code in other flows in the code and it works fine.

Observation;

- The code does nothing seemingly asynchronously.
- The JQuery approach to show and hide a certain element at the start and end of the function is never seen.

Questions;

- Is the expectation to have the `__method1` and `__method2` run asynchronously in such a code structure incorrect? What am I missing?
- Why would the `show()` and `hide()` methods not be working as expected here?

P.S - In other areas where similar `async-await` and the `show-hide` approach is being used, I have `fetch()` calls and promises in the picture.
This method event however is pure computation and no fetch API's are involved.

Comment: "*The code does nothing seemingly asynchronously.*" then most likely `__method1()` and `__method2()` are not asynchronous. Slapping an async and await in the code doesn't make the code multithreaded or parallel or anything of the like. If the code is blocking, it's still blocking.

Comment: if you're using any loops (for, while, do...while) inside `__method1` or `__method2` then they will behave synchronously regardless of async-await

Comment: And the show/hide will be without effect, because the paint cycle will only occur after the microtasks (executing your methods) have completed.

Comment: So basically: What are `_method1` and `_method2`? Without knowing that, we can't help you further than the comments above do.

Comment: Some ideas: use `setTimeout` and break up your calculation in small chunks. Or use Web workers for executing the methods (and hope your DOM still doesn't block).

Comment: As @trincot has stated, simply wrapping your `__method1()` `__method2()` and `$().hide()` in a `settimeout(_, 1)` will allow the dom to at least `show()` the initial div. It will still block the UI while your methods are executing, but the div will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments....The __method1 and 2 are not async. They are just normal functions being called to read some huge maps and perform some actions there. Are we saying that making the ```method1``` and ```method2``` as ```async``` would help?

Comment: No, we are not saying that.